# Will Apache Ignite make a proxy out of a remote service proxy method return if it is my own type?

Tags: ignite

One of my service methods returns an non-primitive object of **my own class**.

The service is cluster-singleton, so I expect it to be used mostly through it's proxy on different nodes.

What will this method return? Will it be a proxy of my object too? Or will it attempt to serialize it on remote and deserialize it on a local machine?

The trick is that the **object returned contains a reference to the service itself**.

1. If serialize/deserialize happens, I expect Ignite to replace this reference with a service proxy during deserialization on a local machine. Will it happen?
2. Otherwise I expect it to make a proxy out of the returned object, though it is a little bit worse scenario due to subsequent bigger network interactions while working with this object.
3. The worst scenario would be that the service proxy can't return anything except primitives or standards.

Digging into the source code and the docs, I failed to locate my answer, please advise. What will happen:

1. deserialize/replace internal refs;
2. proxyfy;
3. fail;
4. Other?

Comment: Why return a copy of the service? The caller already has a reference to the service. It feels like you're unnecessarily exposing your implementation to the client. Better to return a copy that doesn't have the reference.

Comment: @StephenDarlington, the service creates an object which needs to keep a reference to the service that has created it for some internal processings. The service instance couldn't be gotten from that object as there is no appropriate getter.

Comment: Exactly: _internal processing_. That data shouldn't be returned to the client. Rather than return the whole service object, you could return a unique identifier so the service could store and retrieve the object on demand.

Comment: I don't want to return the whole service object. I would be fine if Ignite would replace a service object with its proxy during deserialization, for example.

Comment: I would like to make some computations locally instead of delegating it all to the poor remote singleton service, so they are done in the returned object methods. But there is a small piece that needs to be retrieved from the originating service from time to time, because it is a singleton and keeps track of certain collections
> internal processing. That data shouldn't be returned to the client.

Answer (score 0):

1. will happen - your custom object will be serialized and sent across the network.

What happens to your service, I'm not entirely sure. Maybe it will be also serialized and sent across network :) of course, in this case it will become a different instance.

Now, if you had your object refer to service proxy instead of the service itself (raw object outside of Ignite), the result may be different.

Comment: > in this case it will become a different instance

which makes it effectively not a cluster singleton

Comment: Yes. So you need to always retrieve a fresh service proxy on a current node.

Comment: My service doesn't know that it is called from outside and can't get anything from a machine that is calling it remotely, so it can't create an object and put a proxy of itself there instead of itself, so to say   
> if you had your object refer to service proxy instead of the service itself

Comment: Well, your service will definitely get a call of `init()`, this is when it can initialize all it wants. Then, your object can have a field of `@IgniteInstanceResource` and retrieve service proxy by name from it.

Comment: Probably good idea, but I can't follow it because my whole library is Iginte-agnostic, I am just rewriting it to be "Ignite-ready" and all service-oriented, but I don't want to lock it in